# Making bitbucket push my changes to another repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a small node at openshift, which only accepts git pushes. For the sake of having a backup I use bitbucket to store all my projects. I was wondering if it would be possible that when I push my changes to bitbucket, it will automatically push those changes to openshift. This would save me some time to manually push to both locations.

Comment: Can you not just add a shell alias for that?

Comment: Well, I just know the bare basics of git and server deployment, so you have to explain what a shell alias is. Also I just use Netbeans IDE to push to git. My setup is not all that professional.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a shell/command prompt open where you do the pushing via command line. That doesn't take more time for two pushes than for one

Comment: It would also be an option to have Netbeans push to both locations.

Comment: @NiklasB. I just read your comment about the prompt, that would be an option indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to [define a POST hook on Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks) which will ask your node to execute a pull from Bitbucket repo.